# How can I get column descriptions/comments for a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel

In my laravel app, I'd like to get the comments for all the columns of a given SQL Server table.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$query    = "SELECT sys.objects.name AS TableName, sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
                   ep.name AS PropertyName, ep.value AS Description
            FROM sys.objects
            INNER JOIN sys.columns ON sys.objects.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
            CROSS APPLY fn_listextendedproperty(default,
                              'SCHEMA', schema_name(schema_id),
                              'TABLE', sys.objects.name, 'COLUMN', sys.columns.name) ep
            ORDER BY sys.objects.name, sys.columns.column_id";

$columnDetails =  DB::connection($user->getConnectionName())->select(DB::raw($query)
```

This is what my table looks like in DBeaver:

[image]

But, I get this result from my code which gives a "Description" of `null`:

[image]

Have I done something wrong in the query or in the table setup thats causing this to be null?

---

### Additional Info

I added the original comment via the DBeaver UI, thinking that might not do what I think it does, I went back and added another column and comment via SQL with:

```
EXEC laravel.sys.sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 'Some test description', 'schema', 'guest', 'table', 'users', 'column', 'test' GO
```

Which unfortunately results in the same issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query like this:

```
$query    = "select so.name as TableName, sc.name as ColumnName,
                ep.name as PropertyName, ep.value as Description
            from sys.objects so
            join sys.columns sc on so.object_id = sc.object_id
            join sys.extended_properties ep
                on sc.object_id = ep.major_id and sc.column_id = ep.minor_id
            order by so.name, sc.column_id";

$columnDetails =  DB::connection($user->getConnectionName())->select(DB::raw($query)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that produces the same result (ie MS_Description is still null). Perhaps I've set the `MS_Description` incorrectly? I assume that adding a "Description in DBeaver's UI is setting the `MS_Description` extended property for the column, but maybe its not?

Comment: Maybe you're using an user without metadata permission in your query.